# Запятая перед союзом И

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, нужна ли запятая перед союзом И: "В кабинете стоял стол, обтянутый зеленым сукном, и старый деревянный стул". Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конечно, нужна. В этом предложении с двух сторон запятыми выделяется причастный оборот

Answer (score 0):

Виктор прав. Запятая нужна. Причастный оборот после определяемого слова.